# unterminated `s' command, can't find my mistake

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
sudo wbinfo --group-info GROUPNAME| sed -r -e 's/(?:DOMAIN\\(\w+),?)|(?:[^]+:)/$1/g'
```

This command results in an

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
```

The output of

```
sudo wbinfo --group-info GROUPNAME
```

is like

```
GROUPNAME:x:0123456789:DOMAIN\user1,DOMAIN\user2,DOMAIN\user3,...,DOMAIN\userN
```

I tried escaping all instances of `(` with `\(`, `\` with `\\` (also `\\` with `\\\\`)

```
sudo wbinfo --group-info GROUPNAME| sed -r -e s/'(?:DOMAIN\\(\w+),?)|(?:[^]+:)'/$1/g
```

(changed quoted area)

```
sudo wbinfo --group-info GROUPNAME| sed -r -e s/'(?:DOMAIN\\(\w+),?)|(?:[^]+:)/\1/g'
```

(`\1` instead of `$1`)

I still don't know how to get what I need:

```
user1 user2 user3 ... userN
```

Comment: `[^]` is not a valid part of a regex unless the set is eventually terminated, which it isn't in your case. `[^]]` would be (matching anything except `]`), but I'm not sure if that is what you meant to use there. Anyway, this sort of looks like you want to use parts of Perl regexes that sed doesn't support, so you might want to use Perl instead.

Comment: `sed -r` uses [POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), not PCRE.

Comment: That regexp looks like ERE with Gnu extensions to me. It doesn't look like it contains any PCRE specific stuff (I should know because I don't use PCRE)

Comment: @slebetman Non-capturing groups `(?:)` are PCRE and not ERE.

Comment: GNU grep will work here, it has PCRE mode: `grep -oP '(?<=\\)\w+'`

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Tcl implemented non-capturing groups as ERE before PCRE existed.

Comment: @siebetman Didn't know that - mainly saying that ERE in grep and sed don't have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;TR

Your attempt is too complicated, you can simply use this:

```
sed -r 's/[^\]+DOMAIN\\([[:alnum:]]+)/\1 /g'
```

---

About the syntax error:

You are using `sed -r` which enables extended posix regular expressions. Note that in extended posix regular expressions the `?` is used as a quantifier for *optional repetition*. You you need to escape it:

```
sed -r -e 's/(\?:DOMAIN\\(\w+),\?)|(\?:[^]+:)/$1/g'
```

However, there is still a problem left with the regex: you are using `[^]`. Note that the `^` when used in a character class, negates the match of that class. You are using the `^` but missed to say which characters should not matched. You need to put in something like:

```
sed -r -e 's/(\?:DOMAIN\\(\w+),\?)|(\?:[^abc]+:)/$1/g'
```

Comment: I did not miss saying which characters should not match, i thought it's interpreted as 'all characters that do not match NOTHING', similiar to [/s/S].

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ ... | awk -F'\\\\' -v RS=, '{print $2}'
```

will give the result one user per line, if you want them to appear on a single line add `... | xargs`

Comment: Or, set ORS to a space

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach with sed:

```
sed -r -e 's/^.*://' -e 's/[^,]+\\//g' -e 's/,/ /g'
```

First remove all the stuff before the last colon in the line,
then remove all the domain parts (non-commas followed by a backslash),
then change commas to spaces.